# Creation of single zip containing multiple zips fails for ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, apache-commons-compress

I am using commons compress to zip multiple files and send it the client from a Servlet.
The files could be a combination of any type of files(text, video, audio, archives, images etc). I take the inputStream of file and write to ServletOutputStream using IOUtils.copy(is, os).
The code usually works fine for any document combination but when there is a request to download files that contain more than 1 zip, I get `java.io.IOException: Closed`
As a result, the zip file created is corrupted even though the size of zip is summation of individual filesizes(I am not using compression).

I tried to locally create zip and use `FileOutputStream` instead of `response.getOutputStream()` in the constructor of `ZipArchiveOutputStream` and it **succeeds**.
So, it looks like the problem exists for `ServletOutputStream`.

Can anyone suggest any workaround.

Here is my code :

```
`try (ZipArchiveOutputStream zos = new ZipArchiveOutputStream( response.getOutputStream())) {
        //get fileList
        for(File file : files) {
           addFileToZip(zos, file.getName(), new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        }
        zos.close()
    }
```

`

```
public static void addFileToZip(ZipArchiveOutputStream zipOutputStream, String filename, InputStream inputStream) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if(zipOutputStream != null && inputStream != null) {
        try {
            zipOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(new ZipArchiveEntry(filename));
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, zipOutputStream);
            logger.debug("fileAddedToZip :" + filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error in adding file :" + filename, e); 
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
                zipOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry(); //**Starts to fail here after 1st zip is added**
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error in closing zip entry :" + filename, e);
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Here is the exception trace : 
`

```
java.io.IOException: Closed
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:627)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:577)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeOut(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:1287)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeOut(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:1272)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeDataDescriptor(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:997)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:461)
        at xxx.yyy.zzz.util.ZipUtils.addFileToZip(ZipUtils.java:110)
```

line 110 is `zipOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry(); //**Starts to fail here after 1st zip is added**`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the inpputStream an why you close it in the addFileToZip() ?

Comment: inputStream is the `FileInputStream` of the zip that I want to add. I am closing it to free its resources once its copied.

Comment: Apart from removing the extraneous `zos.close()` you could try `zipOutputStream.flush()` before `closeArchiveEntry()` because I cannot see anything else wrong.

Comment: Tried `zipOutputStream.flush()` but it doesn't works. Also, the zip creation is successful for any other file type combination except when the files have more than 1 zip file.

Comment: does anyone has a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `try-with-resources` which automatically closes the stream you create in it, and yet you also close it manually, and therefore when the JVM tries to auto-close it is when you get `java.io.IOException: Closed` exception because it is already closed.

If you use `try-with-resources`, you don't need to close the streams you create in it. Remove your manual `zos.close()` statement:

```
try (ZipArchiveOutputStream zos =
         new ZipArchiveOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {

    //get fileList
    for(File file : files) {
       addFileToZip(zos, attachment.getFileName(), is);
    }
} // Here zos will be closed automatically!
```

Also note that once `zos` is closed, it will also close the servlet's underlying `OutputStream` so you will not be able to add further entries. You have to add all before it is closed.

Comment: I edited my code to show the correct location of closing parenthesis for the try. As you can see, the automatic closing of `zos` would only happen when I am done adding all files. But, the problem here is that any subsequent zip addition after 1st starts failing(look for my comment in 2nd code snippet).

Comment: Do you properly create the `is` input stream which you pass to your `addFileToZip()` method? Please post all your code.

Comment: Edited the code. @icza the problem here is not how I get the stream but  rather why the code works for **all** other cases and file combinations except those containing more than 1 zip. Why does the call `zipOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry()` starts to fail after initial entry & how can I make it work for more than 1 zip?

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace and indicate which line it is in your code.

Comment: After the `try` block the `zos` stream and the servlet's output stream is closed. You're not trying to add more entries after that, right?

Comment: No, I am not. Like I said before, it works for all cases except when more than 1 zip are added.

Comment: Here is the exception trace :`java.io.IOException: Closed at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:627) at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:577) at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeOut(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:1287) at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeOut(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:1272) at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.writeDataDescriptor(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:997)`